# Is this a maximum leaf spanning tree?

Tags: graph-theory, trees, discrete-optimization

[image]

This is non-oriented weightless graph. I need to find the maximum leaf spanning tree for this graph. Am I made a correct maximum leaf spanning tree like in this pic [image], or not? Thank you for the answers. So, the maximum number of leaves is 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A spanning tree of a Graph G is a tree that include all vertices of the original graph. Here your first graph got 6 vertices while the second have only have 5. It doesnt include the vertex F.

To find the maximum leaf spanning tree. An easy solution would be too find the minimum Connected Dominating set. You can read more about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_dominating_set).

In this case, the minimum connected dominating set would be {B,E}. So the leaf would be the four other vertices.

[image]

Comment: So, if I add one more vertex F, for example as a kid for E vertex, then it will be the maximum leaf spanning tree?

Comment: @Liuzili Well if you add the vertex F as a kid of the vertex E, you would still only have 3 leafs as E is no longer a leaf. I added an exemple of a maximum leaf spanning tree in my original answer

Comment: Thank You so much. And what algorithm do you use to determine which node to take as the root? Is it the one that has the most adjacent vertices? And another question, how to calculate how many operations would be needed to construct a maximum leaf spanning tree?

Comment: The node you should as root doesnt matter as long as he is part of the minimum Connected Dominating, you could for exemple use E as root if you wanted. You just need to make a tree out of the node from the Dominating set first and then add the leafs. For the number of operations you would need to obtain a MLST, both algorithm for minimum Connected Dominating and maximum leaf spanning tree are np complete, meaning that there are no efficient way to find the solution. For exemple the complexity of the minimum dominating set is O(1.8021^n).

Comment: You can read more about it [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1570866705000225) and [here](http://cedric.cnam.fr/~bentzc/INITREC/Files/AP1.pdf)